# Mixing HTML5 elements with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup

I'm struggling to understand the correct, or at least, typical, structure for an HTML5 page, specifically, one using Bootstrap.

I get that Bootstrap uses `div` elements on their site to represent generic content, but most templates that I come across will use `header`, `nav`, and `footer`, but that's about where their semantics end, and the inconsistencies are really bothering me.

I'm also trying to determine the best HTML5 structure, but it's pretty scattered. A lot of "tutorials" will ignore the `main` element or not use any containers.

To avoid using unnecessary `div` elements, this is the structure I currently have for a blog post, but even this seems excessive as I'm not 100% sure on the best way to use Bootstrap classes with HTML5 elements:

```
<body>

    <nav>
    </nav>

    <header>
    </header>

    <div class="container blog-post">
        <div class="row">
            <main>
                <section class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            [Post title/byline]
                        </header>
                        [Post content]
                    </article>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="col-lg-4 col-lg-4">
        [Sidebar content]
    </aside>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Should I also add the `row` class to the `main` element instead? I want to learn, so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a page with a single blog post (instead of a list of blog posts)?

Comment: Yes, in WordPress world, single.php.

Comment: In that case the `section` element seems to be wrong. `article` is a sectioning element, too, so the `section` would create another entry in the outline, which doesn’t seem to make sense. Using `section` like this makes sense for a list of blog posts (i.e., several `article` elements inside that `section`). -- And I guess you intended to have the "[Post content]" outside of the `header`.

Comment: I see. That clears up some confusion on the use of the two, also. Yes, I did, will update the post.